# The Laplace transform of $t^{-3/2}e^{-1/t}$ is denoted $F(s)$. Show that $\frac{dF}{ds} = -\frac{F}{s^{1/2}}$.

Tags: laplace-transform

> The Laplace transform of $t^{-3/2}e^{-1/t}$ is denoted $F(s)$. Show that
>   $$\frac{dF}{ds} = -\frac{F}{s^{1/2}}$$

not sure how to get this.

I tried differentiating $F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-3/2}e^{-1/t}e^{-st}dt$
$$ \frac{dF}{ds} = \int_{0}^{\infty}-t^{-1/2}e^{-1/t}e^{-st}dt$$ Maybe better using table of laplace transform but not sure.

Comment: $$F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-3/2}e^{-1/t}\color{red}{e}^{-st}dt$$

Comment: fixed. @Nosrati

Comment: Check your derivative.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ust=1$ or $st=\dfrac{1}{u}$ then
$$\frac{dF}{ds} = \int_{0}^{\infty}-t^{-1/2}e^{-1/t}e^{-st}dt=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{s}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-3/2}e^{-1/u}e^{-su}\ du=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{s}}F$$

Comment: +1, Out of curiosity, how do you know what to substitute? Is it experience? :-)

Comment: @paulplusx it was by chance $:)$.

Comment: @paulplusx Did you know according to some doctors, walking fast is the best form of exercise!

Comment: I was just praising your intuitions :-)